# Making a cell clickable in a table using angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Answering this question will require expertise in Angularjs directives and jquery

I am displaying a simple table. What I want is when users click on any cell.. it should be selected and then the user should be able to manuever the cursor using keyboard.

Anyone any clues how this can be achieved ?

plnkr here :
http://plnkr.co/edit/whfYEOV1MV2Rrs4i4g7b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I forked and updated your Plunker. I actually did the same kind of table using a custom directive. If you're doing a table, you should use semantic markup. That's why I modified your HTML.

Then, I updated your `select-me` directive to show you how I've done the auto-selection on click and how I implemented the arrow keys navigation.

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/v6dWy2LwOcYDXPfC6WPY?p=preview)

**layout.html**

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="element in header" class="header-cells" style="width:{{element.width}}px">
      <th>{{element.column}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="element in body" data-indexrow="{{$index}}">
      <td ng-repeat="h in header" class="custom-row" data-indexcol="{{$index}}">
        <input type="text" ng-model="element[h.column]" class="body-cell" style="width:{{h.width}}px" select-me>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**selectMe directive (JS)**

```
ct.directive("selectMe", function() {
  return ({
    restrict: "A",
    //    templateUrl: 'sortdropdown.html',
    link: link
  });

  function link(scope, element, attributes) {

    element.on('click', function(e) {
      element.select();
    });

    element.on('keyup', function(e) {
      var $input = angular.element(this),
          $td = $input.parent(),
          $tr = $td.parent(),
          indexrow = parseInt($tr.attr('data-indexrow'),10),
          indexcol = parseInt($td.attr('data-indexcol'),10);

      console.log(indexrow);
      console.log(indexcol);

      // up arrow
      if (e.keyCode === 38) {
        //move up
      }
      // down arrow
      if (e.keyCode === 40) {
        //move down
      }
      // left arrow
      if (e.keyCode === 37) {
        //move left
      }
      // right arrow
      if (e.keyCode === 39) {
        //move right
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks glepretre.. that looks simple enough and works

Comment: @glepretre..could you also advice how i can introduce movement between the cells ?

Comment: @JamesHans I added attributes on rows and cols to index them. And I showed you how to get them in your directive. I let you get the right input to move on with jQlite or jQuery and handle the particular cases (first and last line, idem for column). ;) Don't forget to vote me up please! :p